# how to remove back slashes from mysql dump table while importing in postgreSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql

I am facing back slashes() problem during migrating database from MYSQL to postgrSQL.
My problem is I have many large mysql tables dump(with sql formate) around 2gb and try to import in postgreSQL database. IN mysql dump file there are many back slashes in many columns so if I am try to import in postgreSQL the it through an exception. I have tried many solutions but did not worked yet.
and the mysql dump files are very large so I am unable to set it manually.
you can see the mysql code below.

MYSQL CODE:

```
INSERT INTO Leads 
(921347,NULL,'Lee\'s Summit','MO','64081','1983-09-24',NULL,'75.81.43.181',NULL,0,'cash');
```

so please suggest any solution. Thanks in advance....!!!!!!

Comment: Can you replace `\'` with `''`?  Depending on your data, you may run into issues with multiple slashes, so you may need a more robust solution, but this is the general solution.

Comment: actually i have already tried but got an ERROR:  out of memory
DETAIL:  Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 0 bytes by 1202157801 more bytes.  
I have used this code to remove back slashes 
sed "s/\\\'/\'\'/g" Leads.sql | sed "s/\\\r/\r/g" | sed "s/\\\n/\n/g" > escaped-my.sql

Comment: I think in this case you are better off using an ETL solution like Kettle/Pentaho Data Integration. It works very well across multiple databases and has lots of options to format data before inserting it into the database.

Comment: Why no just remove the unwanted backslashes (escaped quotes) with a commandline tool like sed? In windows I believe something like powergrep would be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape these slashes by doubling them up:

INSERT INTO Leads (921347,NULL,'Lee\'s ...

How you do that depends on the tools at your disposal. If you don't have an editor that can search and replace for you then you could write a php script and process the file using preg_replace.

Personally I would not use sql dump files to migrate data, apart from this sort of problem they are just too slow. Far better to use Navicat\Toad\Heidi or the like to do it with. Navicat is best but you have to pay for it while others are free.

Answer (score 0):

if you add E before quoted string it will run, like

```
INSERT INTO Leads (921347,NULL,'Lee\'s Summit','MO','64081','1983-09-24',NULL,'75.81.43.181',NULL,0,'cash');
```

will become

```
INSERT INTO Leads (921347,NULL,e'Lee\'s Summit','MO','64081','1983-09-24',NULL,'75.81.43.181',NULL,0,'cash');
```

you can sed all `,'` to be `,e'` and run insert statements

Eg: I created a file with your statement and sed all occurrences:

```
cat mysql.sql
INSERT INTO Leads (921347,NULL,'Lee\'s Summit','MO','64081','1983-09-24',NULL,'75.81.43.181',NULL,0,'cash');
INSERT INTO Leads (921347,NULL,'Lee\'s Summit','MO','64081','1983-09-24',NULL,'75.81.43.181',NULL,0,'cash');
sed -i.bak s/,'/,e'/g mysql.sql
cat mysql.sql
INSERT INTO Leads (921347,eNULL,e'Lee\'s Summit',e'MO',e'64081',e'1983-09-24',eNULL,e'75.81.43.181',eNULL,e0,e'cash');
INSERT INTO Leads (921347,eNULL,e'Lee\'s Summit',e'MO',e'64081',e'1983-09-24',eNULL,e'75.81.43.181',eNULL,e0,e'cash');
cat mysql.sql.bak
INSERT INTO Leads (921347,NULL,'Lee\'s Summit','MO','64081','1983-09-24',NULL,'75.81.43.181',NULL,0,'cash');
INSERT INTO Leads (921347,NULL,'Lee\'s Summit','MO','64081','1983-09-24',NULL,'75.81.43.181',NULL,0,'cash');
```

So you have .bak of original and mysql.sql converted for postgres...

**Update 2:**
You can use Oracle style to change not all quoted strings, but escaped quotes only:

```
sed -e "s/\\\\'/''/g" mysql.sql
INSERT INTO Leads (921347,NULL,'Lee''s Summit','MO','64081','1983-09-24',NULL,'75.81.43.181',NULL,0,'cash');
INSERT INTO Leads (921347,NULL,'Lee''s Summit','MO','64081','1983-09-24',NULL,'75.81.43.181',NULL,0,'cash');
```

Comment: "_and the mysql dump files are very large so I am unable to set it manually_" ...

Comment: Thanks for your solution, actually in my query all values are comma separated like this ,
INSERT INTO Leads (921347,eNULL,e'Lee\'s Summit',e'MO',e'64081',e'1983-09-24',eNULL,e'75.81.43.181',eNULL,e0,e'cash'),e(921347,eNULL,e'Lee\'s Summit',e'MO',e'64081',e'1983-09-24',eNULL,e'75.81.43.181',eNULL,e0,e'cash')
and many more. So it adds after every row end so in postgresql it through error.
Please find error:-
psql ERROR:  syntax error at or near "e"
LINE 1: ...',eNULL,e0,e195,e'2434',e'211',e'',e'',eNULL,e18),e(41645,e'.....

Comment: well the use less safe, but more efficient in your case:
sed -e "s/\\\\'/''/g" mysql.sql
INSERT INTO Leads (921347,NULL,'Lee''s Summit','MO','64081','1983-09-24',NULL,'75.81.43.181',NULL,0,'cash');
INSERT INTO Leads (921347,NULL,'Lee''s Summit','MO','64081','1983-09-24',NULL,'75.81.43.181',NULL,0,'cash');

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
shell> mysqldump --tab=/tmp yourdatabase
```

Then for each table use http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-copy.html

```
COPY country FROM '/tmp/yourtable';
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no simple solution doing it for large databases, please read the following wikibook:

**Converting MySQL to PostgreSQL**
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Converting_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL

There you find examples how to migrate your dumpfile or a suggestion to use CSV files instead of dump files.